# Python read http: html page as seen in browser - with javascripts results

Tags: javascript, python, http

Can I get `http` page as seen in browser - fully formed after `javascripts` are run? No need to submit data and press buttons. IMHO it's standard task, where can I see example to run all scripts and get result?

Via:

```
u = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.*')
data = u.read()
```

I get page as seen if I choose view source in browser. However, when I inspect elements on page, I see how code expands, e.g.:

```
<div class="js-events-container"></div>
```

expands to:

```
<div class="js-events-container">    <table class="zebra noBorderTbl" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
...
        </tr>
            </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i see js in the class name, it is probably javascript, i think there isn't a way to get the full page with urllib. you need to pull the site after the javascript starts. you will need selenium or phantomjs to do the job.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't my task rather standard? Maybe there are examples how to do that - just load page without providing inputs (could not find now)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a look to this particular library [dryscape](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dryscrape). It is javascript aware as per documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I now load page using `selenium`, then get `page_source`. In spite of name, `page_source` give not page source, but page result after java scripts are run.